# Joomla URL: Using format: www.xyz.com/section/category/article

Tags: joomla-sef-urls

I'm new to Joomla, and have switched on SEF URLs. However, the issue is that it returns my links in the format:

www.site.com/category/article

I'd like it to return articles in the format:

www.site.com/section/category/article

I've searched Stack Overflow and haven't found the answer...wondering if anyone could help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Like I've read at http://docs.joomla.org/SEF_URLs_in_Joomla!_1.5 you had to change the htaccess.txt to .htaccess. This is clear, because the URL-format is formatted with the mod_rewrite module.

If you want to do it by yourself, I recommend you reading http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html and learn how to use ReWrite-Rules. Then you can customize your URLs how you like.
The Rewrite-Rules are in the .htaccess file.